# Tkinter: Grid containing frame containing grid

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, logic, calculator

This is slightly exposing the entire program I'm building but it's just the front end anyways. If you guys want to make the app yourself, go ahead. :P

So, as the title says, I'm trying to make a grid that contains a frame that contains a grid, and I have looked at a few similar questions and don't completely get the answers, likely because I'm new to guis and tkinter and the solutions are often suited to their specific program. So here's a similar problem suited to mine.

What I'm trying to do is build something with the overall frame structure that looks like this: [GUI Frame structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOJOe.png), where each frame besides the ioFrame is a 2x2 grid. The ioFrame contains two things: an input row and an output row. In short, this is a calculator that computes logic inputs and your only "numbers" are true and false.

Here's my code atm:

```
from tkinter import *; 


class calculator:

    #def update(self, 

    def __init__(self, window):
        """
        Constructor method.
        """

        self.toCompute = []; self.In = StringVar(); self.Out = StringVar();

        # Window title
        window.title("Logic Calculator");

        # The set of 5 frames.
        ioFrame = Frame(window, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=3); ioFrame.grid(row=0); ioFrame.pack();
        nwFrame = Frame(window); nwFrame.grid(row=1,column=0); nwFrame.pack();
        neFrame = Frame(window); neFrame.grid(row=1,column=1); neFrame.pack();
        swFrame = Frame(window); swFrame.grid(row=2,column=0); swFrame.pack();
        seFrame = Frame(window); seFrame.grid(row=2,column=1); seFrame.pack();

        # Top 2 rows: the IO portion
        Label(ioFrame, textvariable=self.In, relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=0, sticky=W);
        Label(ioFrame, textvariable=self.Out).grid(row=1, sticky=E);

        # Top left 2x2 Frame: [ ( | ) ][ T | F ]
        brlButton = Button(nwFrame, text='(', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=0);
        brrButton = Button(nwFrame, text=')', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=1);
        truButton = Button(nwFrame, text='T', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=0);
        falButton = Button(nwFrame, text='F', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=1);

        # Top right 2x2 Frame: [ AND | OOR ][ NND | NOR ]
        andButton = Button(neFrame, text='and', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=0);
        oorButton = Button(neFrame, text='oor', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=1);
        nndButton = Button(neFrame, text='nnd', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=0);
        norButton = Button(neFrame, text='nor', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=1);

        # Bottom left 2x2 Frame: [ SSO | IIF ][ NSO | NIF ]
        andButton = Button(swFrame, text='sso', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=0);
        oorButton = Button(swFrame, text='iif', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=1);
        nndButton = Button(swFrame, text='nso', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=0);
        norButton = Button(swFrame, text='nif', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=1);

        # Bottom right 2x2 Frame:[ EEQ | NEG ][ NEQ | === ]
        eeqButton = Button(seFrame, text='eeq', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=0);
        negButton = Button(seFrame, text='neg', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=1);
        neqButton = Button(seFrame, text='neq', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=0);
        comButton = Button(seFrame, text='=', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=1);



if __name__ == "__main__": # Only runs program if this specfic file is opened.

    window = Tk(); # The window
    calculator(window);
    window.mainloop();
```

I still have to add the commands to these (which I've written in a separate file already), but I was just trying to get the gui done separately for now.

My problem, is that my code outputs this result instead: [Current GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbCMR.png). This is clearly way off from what I was going for. And being new to this, I probably have a list of problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of python are you using? I'm using python3 and the code provided doesn't even run

Comment: @Nelson How do you find out? Do you know what or where the error is, by any chance?

Comment: @Nelson Version 3.3.2.

Comment: I'm about to post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume here that you came to python from another language because of all the semicolons. In python, **YOU DO NOT NEED SEMICOLONS**. I understand at the top if you *really* want to keep those variables all on one line, but each line in your script should not end in a semicolon.

Secondly, if you print out the value of any button you you have put in a variable, you will see that it is `None` instead of a `tkinter.Button` object. This is because of that `.grid(...)` call at the end of the line (`grid` returns `None`). Typically, I only put widgets into a variable if I intend on using it later in the app. If not, I do what you did with the labels, just called them without `some_variable_name =` in front of it. If you ever try to do anything with those button variables later, it will not work because they are all `None`.

As mentioned in the comments, I was unable to get your provided code to run because you are using `.grid(...)` *and* `.pack(...)` to place the Frames on the window. You only need one. That was actually what caused the errors for me. Think of the window or Frame as a container; if you use `grid` to put something in that container, then you cannot use `pack` to put something else in the container. The different methods of placing widgets conflict with each other. I believe the output you got was because it would place the Frames using `grid`, then re-place them using `pack` which is why they are vertically aligned.

---

So taking all of this into consideration, this is what I have:

```
########## Frames ##########

# this is what the frames should look like in your code
frame = Frame(window, ...)
frame.grid(row=, column=)



########## Buttons ##########

# if you want to keep the buttons in variables
btn = Button(parent, text='', width=, height=)
btn.grid(row=, column=)

# or

# if the buttons don't have to be in variables, like your Labels
Button(parent, text='', width=, height=).grid(row=, column=)
```

There is also a typo with your button variables. In the `Bottom left 2x2 Frame` section, the button variables names should be changed to match the section title (if you are keeping the variables names):

```
ssoButton = ...
iifButton = ...
nsoButton = ...
nifButton = ...
```

The button variables are just references to the Button objects, so reusing a name doesn't matter, unless you want to use the buttons later in your code. In that case, it will cause issues, like I said before.

I updated part of the code so you can see what it should look like:

[image: Fixed code]

EDIT: I almost forgot about the ioFrame. It should be allowed to expand to fill the space provided at the top, but it's not. To fix this:

```
ioFrame = Frame(window, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=3, bg='green')
ioFrame.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, sticky=N+E+S+W)
```

I set the background to green just to make sure it filled the space, and set the StringVars to some dummy text for testing (done like this: `self.In.set('text here')` to change the text). After all changes were made, this is my output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the semicolons, Ik I don't need them. It's just that I wanted to be consistent with the code from other languages. Python was actually the first that I learned.

Comment: @OsamaKawish You are welcome. That's actually pretty funny. Just wanted to make sure you knew :)